# Kalman filter in GPS watches

Tags: gps, kalman-filter

I have a simple question that I don't seem to find anywhere, do typical GPS watches only use GPS data or do they also use other sensores and fuse the information with a Kalman filter?

What is usually the case?

Comment: When you say "only use GPS data" are you enquiring about only resolving position, or about other metrics that some watches report such as cadence?

Comment: @asandwhich I'm also implying other metrics.

Comment: Many high end running watches have several sensors such as barometric altimeters, accelerometers, and gyroscopes. In some cases there might be a chest strap with an extra accel/gyro sensor paired with the watch as well. It would probably not be a stretch to assume a kalman filter is used for certain metrics, for example combining accel + gyro to better determine cadence.

Comment: Whether or not GPS is combined with another sensor (accelerometer) to do something like dead reckoning would depend on the watch, as it may be difficult for the manufacturer to get useful info out of such a setup.

Comment: @RuiLima What sort of other metrics are you implying? Things like cadence do not require GPS data, and a watch typically doesn't require high enough position accuracy to require a Kalman filter.

Comment: @uint128_t I'm not implying other metrics, I was just curious if the sport watches use other sensors to help improve GPS accuracy. But from what I've learned here it seems it would be somewhat of an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual case (as of Nov 2016) is a barometer but no inertial sensor in wrist-worn devices.

MEMS sensors are being worked on, f.e. [Invensense](https://www.invensense.com) has introduced a [miniaturized sensor platform](http://ir.invensense.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=237953&p=irol-newsArticle&ID=2126314) for wrist-worn devices recently. I do not know any products that already use this.

One thing to be expected from inertial sensors is extended battery life, because the GNSS receiver can be powered down more often. Aiding the tracking loop with acceleration stress and jerks is typically not relevant for wearables (unless you take them for a roller coaster ride).